# CSS: Unable to set top property more than 100%

Tags: html, css

I am not able to set a top property more than 100%. Below is my CSS code:

Refer to the ruleset `.blue3`. The top property has to be more than 100% to align the elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.green, .green:before, .green:after, .blue, .blue:before, .blue:after, .blue1, .blue1:before, .blue1:after, .blue2, .blue2:before, .blue2:after, .blue3:before, .blue3:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.green, .blue, .blue1, .blue2, .blue3{
  position: relative;
  opacity: .5;
}

.green:before, .blue:before, .blue1:before, .blue2:before, .blue3:before {
  top: -50%;
}

.green:after, .blue:after, .blue1:after, .blue2:after, .blue3:after {
  bottom: -50%;
}

.green {
  background-color: rgb(10,210,30);
}

.green:before, .green:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
}

.blue {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0,20,210);
  left: 50%;
  top: 17%;
}
.blue1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0,20,210);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.blue2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0,20,210);
  left: 50%;
  top: 83%;
}

.blue3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0,20,210);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 200%;
}


.blue:before, .blue:after, .blue1:after, .blue1:before, .blue2:before, .blue2:after, .blue3:before, .blue3:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>1st Main Task</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <section class="circle">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
          <section class="blue"></section>
           <section class="blue1"></section>
          <section class="blue2"></section>
          <section class="blue3"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="circle">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
          <section class="blue"></section>
           <section class="blue1"></section>
          <section class="blue2"></section>
          <section class="blue3"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="circle">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
          <section class="blue"></section>
           <section class="blue1"></section>
          <section class="blue2"></section>
          <section class="blue3"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="circle">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
          <section class="blue"></section>
           <section class="blue1"></section>
          <section class="blue2"></section>
          <section class="blue3"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="circle">
        <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
          <section class="blue"></section>
           <section class="blue1"></section>
          <section class="blue2"></section>
          <section class="blue3"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
         <section class="wrapper">
          <section class="green"></section>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can we figure out what's wrong with the code without seeing the html

Comment: Hi @Huangism. I have added the html content. Anyways I just wanted to know why am I not able to set top value to more than 100%

Comment: is this shape a kind of homework somewhere ? ... i aleardy saw 5 question dealing with this shape

Comment: Not sure what you mean by cannot set it, I just edited it in inspector and you can set top over 100%. Make sure to set bottom to auto if you are going to set top. Update your question with more detail of how you cannot set it to 100%+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.green, .green:before, .green:after, .blue, .blue:before, .blue:after, .blue1, .blue1:before, .blue1:after, .blue2, .blue2:before, .blue2:after, .blue3, .blue3:before, .blue3:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I guess .blue3 was missing in the css

Comment: Yeah. I had figured that out. Anyways Thank you for taking your time here. Really appreciate that effort.